# How to open a database connection on termination of a WinForm?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

I am looking for a way to send data to my database server when the application is closed via killing/termination. So far, I have found that it is possible to run some code after the `Application.Run()` of the Form, However, code seems to stop after the connection opening function. Below is a demonstration.

```
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new xxxForm());
            Console.WriteLine("Runs Fine.");
            if (UserSession != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Runs Fine.");

                MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=xxx; database=xxx; UID=xxx; password=xxx");
                Console.WriteLine("Runs Fine");
                Connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("STOPS RUNNING");
                string query = "UPDATE users SET clientstatus = 'offline' WHERE uuid = '" + UserSession.UUID + "' ";
                var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, Connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Doesn't Run");
                UserSession = null;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Doesn't Run");
        }
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this as I cant seem to find much documentation on doing something like this.

Note: I have written a lot of code under this before and it works, connections dont however for some reason.

Comment: Q: Is there a way to [do something upon termination of WinForm]?  A: Yes: simply define an event handler on [Application.ApplicationExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit).  Q: Is the code you've shown actually from a "WinForm" app?  If so, which platform are you targeting?  Win32?  .Net?  .Net Core 3.1?  .Net 5?

Comment: When you say killing/termination, are you meaning via the task manager?

Comment: `However, code seems to stop after the connection opening function.`, does the program exit, any errors thrown?

Comment: ApplicationExit works, but it doesnt work with killing the application, only with scheduled exits like `Application.Exit()`. Yes I mean task manager or other methods of "forcing" the app to close. I know I could make a secondary application just check if it dies or not but thats ugly and not what I am looking for tbh. Program exits with code "1".

Comment: Well, I would say you're kind of at a dead end then.  Killing the process Kills the process dead, meaning no more code withing that process is going to execute

Comment: Instead of trying to update the users who are offline, work out who is online `from information_schema.processlist`. eg `update users set last_id=connection_id() ...`

Answer (score 1):

> when the application is closed via killing/termination

You can't. Killing the app suspends it's execution and removes it from memory. It doesn't get a chance to do more work

You'll have to infer it instead:

- have a server that all the apps connect to that can detect the loss of connection and use it to mark the user offline
- have your app update a user specific field every X seconds, such as `LastSeenDateTime` column in user table. If the app is killed it will stop updating. Anyone with a LastSeen more than 2X seconds in the past is probably offline